# how to use interceptors in EJB 3 XML

Tags: ejb-3.0

how to configure interceptors in EJB 3 XML files.

I want to use interceptors for invoking EJb life cycle methods using XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follwing configuration in deployment descriptor file.

```
<interceptor-binding>
      <ejb-name>SomeBean</ejb-name>
      <interceptor-class>com.interceptor.DefaultInterceptor</interceptor-class>
      <method>
      <method-name>businessMethod</method-name>
      </method>
   </interceptor-binding>
```